# What should be edited in routing.yml in symfony 3 to create a new route from annotation?

Tags: symfony, symfony-routing

I am quite new to Symfony 3. I created the controller files in the AppBundle itself. No new bundle created. Now I am trying to route a new page and it gives an error. This is what I did.

In `src\AppBundle\Controller\Patient\PatientController.php`

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/patient", name="patient_homepage")
    */
    public function patientHomeAction(Request $request)
    {
        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('Patient/home.html.twig', array()
        );
    }
```

In the `app\Resources\views\base.html.twig`

```
<a href="{{ path('patient_homepage') }}">Home</a>
```

This gives an error as

> "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "patient_homepage" as
>   such route does not exist.") in base.html.twig at line 118."

Do I need to do any changes in the `app\config\routing.yml` also? What am I missing here.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable route in `app/config/routing.yml`

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/Patient/"
    type:     annotation
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```